# Why are these two statements equivalent

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, logic

So my question basically has to do with a switch statement. Why is

```
switch (foo) {
    case 1: case 2:
        bar();
        break;
}
```

the same as:

```
if (foo == 1 || foo == 2) {
    bar();
}
```

It seems to me that with the switch statement, the code under case 1 would execute, and the code under case 2 would be ignored. Please explain to me why this is not the case.

Comment: What language are you referring to here?  Please add the relevant tag.

Comment: Have you looked up how switches work? In every language that I know, each case is *not* executed separately unless separated by a `break`. `case 1` "falls through" into `case 2`.

Comment: Assuming Java, go here and search the page for "fall through": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When evaluating `case` statements, the code will [fall through](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough) until the block is terminated (usually by a `break` statement). So the semantics of the first snippet are as follows:

- If `foo` is `2`, execute `bar()` and then break.
- If `foo` is `1`, execute the block following `case 1:`, which is empty (i.e., do nothing), and then continue (fall through) to the block following `case 2:`, detailed in the previous point
- For any other value, do nothing (as there are no matching `case` blocks.

As you can see, this is equivalent of executing `bar()` in case `foo` is `1` or `2`.

Answer (score 0):

The `break;` statement is fully responsible for breaking out of the switch code block.

A switch statement without a `break;` statement will execute in a very odd order.

```
  switch (2) {
    case 2:
       alert("hello");
    case 3: 
        alert("goodbye");
        break;
    case 4:
         alert("will never show");
  }
```

JavaScript switch statements: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add `break;` at the end of every case statement to stop a case from then executing everything below it.  Otherwise, it falls through.